# Greatest Value of Arg(z)

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

If we are given that | z - 3 - 2i | ≤ 1 and Im(z) ≥ 2 and we shade the region that satisfies both inequalities. What would be the greatest value of arg(z) in this region?

I personally first made a circle with center (3,2) with radius 1 and then a line such that y = 2 and shaded the upper portion of the circle (the one above the line). I got my greatest arg(z) value as 57.8(1dp) but I wanted to verify whether the answer is right or wrong.

*For calculations, I first made a line until the center of the circle and got hyp as sqrt5 and then I found tan(theta) = 2/3 and tan(theta) = 1/sqrt5 and added the two answers.*